# find text in html using Golang's colly/goquery

Tags: html, go, goquery

How can I use colly/goquery to find the numerical values in this html snippet:

```
<body>
 <a href="/xxxx/aaaa" > AAAA </a>,  125.00  <br>
 <a href="/xxxx/bbbb" > BBBB </a>,  235.20  <br>
 <a href="/xxxx/cccc" > CCCC </a>,  145.04  <br>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your specific problem? And be aware of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

This code would get you the numbers as string parts with the space included. You need to trim those and parse as numbers.

**Update:** The code now trims the lines and parses as float.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    html := `<body>
 <a href="/xxxx/aaaa" > AAAA </a>,  125.00  <br>
 <a href="/xxxx/bbbb" > BBBB </a>,  235.20  <br>
 <a href="/xxxx/cccc" > CCCC </a>,  145.04  <br>
</body>`

    reader := strings.NewReader(html)

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    justText := doc.Text()
    lines := strings.Split(justText, "\n")
    for _, line := range lines {
        if len(line) > 0 {
            parts := strings.Split(line, ",")
            number, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(parts[1]), 64)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println(number)
            }
        }
    }
}
```